# How to calculate Arithmetic–logarithmic mean?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, means

As is known to us, the limit of the sequence $\{a_n\},\{b_n\}\ $where$\ a_0=a,b_0=b,a_{n+1}=\dfrac{a_n+b_n}{2},b_{n+1}=\sqrt{a_n b_n}\ $ is related to the Arithmetic–geometric mean of $a,b$, which can be expressed as below

$AG(a,b)=\dfrac{\pi}{2I(a,b)}$, where
$\displaystyle I(a,b)=\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{d\theta}{\sqrt{a^2\cos^2\theta+b^2\sin^2\theta}}$

Now I wonder whether we can calculate the limit of the following sequence

$\ a_0=a,b_0=b,a_{n+1}=\dfrac{a_n+b_n}{2},b_{n+1}=\dfrac{a_n-b_n}{\ln a_n-\ln b_n}$

(without the loss of generality we can assume $a>b>0$)

and I'd like to call this limit the Arithmetic–logarithmic mean

Anyone can solve this?

Comment: https://www.researchgate.net/publication/26534548_The_power_mean_and_the_logarithmic_mean/link/0f3199ac3829de221647664b/download could be of interest (I hope and wish)

Comment: @Claude Leibovici Thanks. As far as I know, $M_0<L<M_{1/3}$ is the sharpest inequality about the power mean and the logarithmic mean, but will it help to determine the exact result? :-)

Comment: No idea but interesting problem. Cheers.